# How can I to render a 2D graph/figure using OpenGL on Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, fractals

I'm making a simple fractal viewing app for Android, just for fun.  I'm also using it as an oppotunity to learn OpenGL since I've never worked with it before.  Using the Android port of the NeHe tutorials as a starting point, my approach is to have one class (FractalModel) which does all the math to create the fractal, and FractalView which does all the rendering.

The difficulty I'm having is in getting the rendering to work.  Since I'm essentially plotting a graph of points of different colors where each point should correspond to 1 pixel, I thought I'd handle this by rendering 1x1 rectangles over the entire screen, using the dimensions to calculate the offsets so that there's a 1:1 correspondence between the rectangles and the physical pixels.  Since the color of each pixel will be calculated independently, I can re-use the same rendering code to render different parts of the fractal (I want to add panning and zooming later on).

Here is the view class I wrote:

```
public class FractalView extends GLSurfaceView implements Renderer {

private float[] mVertices;
private FloatBuffer[][] mVBuffer;
private ByteBuffer[][] mBuffer;
private int mScreenWidth;
private int mScreenHeight;
private float mXOffset;
private float mYOffset;
private int mNumPixels;

//references to current vertex coordinates
private float xTL;
private float yTL;
private float xBL;
private float yBL;
private float xBR;
private float yBR;
private float xTR;
private float yTR;


public FractalView(Context context, int w, int h){
    super(context);
    setEGLContextClientVersion(1);
    mScreenWidth = w;
    mScreenHeight = h;
    mNumPixels = mScreenWidth * mScreenHeight;
    mXOffset = (float)1.0/mScreenWidth;
    mYOffset = (float)1.0/mScreenHeight;
    mVertices = new float[12];
    mVBuffer = new FloatBuffer[mScreenHeight][mScreenWidth];
    mBuffer = new ByteBuffer[mScreenHeight][mScreenWidth];
}


public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl){
    int i,j;    
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);    
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    mapVertices();  
    gl.glColor4f(0.0f,1.0f, 0.0f,.5f);
    for(i = 0; i < mScreenHeight; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < mScreenWidth; j++){
            gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);
            gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mVBuffer[i][j]);
            gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
            gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, mVertices.length / 3);
            gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        }
    }




}

public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int w, int h){
    if(h == 0) {                        //Prevent A Divide By Zero By
        h = 1;                      //Making Height Equal One
    }

    gl.glViewport(0, 0, w, h);  //Reset The Current Viewport
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);    //Select The Projection Matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity();                    //Reset The Projection Matrix

    //Calculate The Aspect Ratio Of The Window
    GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, (float)w / (float)h, 0.1f, 100.0f);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);     //Select The Modelview Matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

}

public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config){
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);            //Enable Smooth Shading
    gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);    //Black Background
    gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);                     //Depth Buffer Setup
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);            //Enables Depth Testing
    gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);             //The Type Of Depth Testing To Do

    //Really Nice Perspective Calculations
    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST); 
}

private void mapVertices(){
    int i,j;
    xTL = -1;
    yTL = 1;
    xTR = -1 + mXOffset;
    yTR = 1;
    xBL = -1;
    yBL = 1 - mYOffset;
    xBR = -1 + mXOffset;
    yBR = 1 - mYOffset;
    for(i = 0; i < mScreenHeight; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < mScreenWidth; j++){
            //assign coords to vertex array         
            mVertices[0] = xBL;
            mVertices[1] = yBL;
            mVertices[2] = 0f;
            mVertices[3] = xBR;
            mVertices[4] = xBR;
            mVertices[5] = 0f;
            mVertices[6] = xTL;
            mVertices[7] = yTL;
            mVertices[8] = 0f;
            mVertices[9] = xTR;
            mVertices[10] = yTR;
            mVertices[11] = 0f;
            //add doubleBuffer
            mBuffer[i][j] = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(mVertices.length * 4);
            mBuffer[i][j].order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            mVBuffer[i][j] = mBuffer[i][j].asFloatBuffer();
            mVBuffer[i][j].put(mVertices);
            mVBuffer[i][j].position(0);
            //transform right
            transformRight();
        }
        //transform down
        transformDown();
        //reset x
        xTL = -1;
        xTR = -1 + mXOffset;
        xBL = -1;
        xBR = -1 + mXOffset;
    }



}

//transform all the coordinates 1 "pixel" to the right
private void transformRight(){
    xTL = xTL + mXOffset; //TL            
    xBL = xBL + mXOffset; //BL
    xBR = xBR + mXOffset; //BR
    xTR = xTR + mXOffset; //TR;
}

//transform all of the coordinates 1 pixel down;
private void transformDown(){
    yTL = yTL - mYOffset;                        
    yBL = yBL - mYOffset;            
    yBR = yBR - mYOffset;           
    yTR = yTR - mYOffset;
}
}
```

Basically I'm trying to do it the same way as [this](http://insanitydesign.com/wp/projects/nehe-android-ports/) (the square in lesson 2) but with far more objects.  I'm assuming 1 and -1 roughly correspond to screen edges, (I know this isn't totally true, but I don't really understand how to use projection matrices and want to keep this as simple as possible unless there's a good resource out there I can learn from) but I understand that OpenGL's coordinates are separate from real screen coordinates.  When I run my code I just get a black screen (it should be green) but LogCat shows the garbage collector working away so I know *something* is happening.  I'm not sure if it's just a bug caused by my just not doing something right, or if it's just REALLY slow.  In either case, what should I do differently?  I feel like I may be going about this all wrong.  I've looked around and most of the tutorials and examples are based on the link above.

Edit: I know I could go about this by generating a texture that fills up the entire screen and just drawing that, though the link I read which mentioned it said it would be slower since you're not supposed to redraw a texture every frame.  That said, I only really need to redraw the texture when the perspective changes, so I could write my code to take this into account.  The main difficulty I'm having currently is drawing the bitmap, and getting it to display correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would imagine that the blank screen is due to the fact that you are swapping buffers so many times, and also the fact that you are generating all your vertex buffers every frame. Thousands of buffer swaps AND thousands of buffer creations in a single frame would be INCREDIBLY slow.

One thing to mention is that Android devices have limited memory, so the garbage collector working away is probably an indication that your buffer creation code is eating up a lot of the available memory and the device is trying to free up some for the creation of new buffers.

I would suggest creating a texture that you fill with your pixel data each frame and then render to a single square that fills the screen. This will increase your speed by a huge amount, and also make your program more flexible.

**Edit:**
Look at the tutorial here : http://www.nullterminator.net/gltexture.html to get an idea on how to create textures and load them. You will basically need to fill BYTE* data with your own data.

If you are changing the data dynamically, you will need to update the texture data. Use the information here : http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture : in the section about Texture image modification.

Comment: I edited my original post to include this, and your explanation for why it doesn't work currently makes perfect sense.  How would I go about creating the texture and drawing it to the screen?

Comment: See my edit for some extra details. As for rendering a fullscreen quad, i'm sure there a many tutorials out there about this (actually if I remember correctly, the first android opengles tutorial shows how to draw in screen coordinates directly).

Comment: I've figured out (mostly) how to put the texture in, the thing is I need to actually "draw" the texture as a bitmap and this is what I'm having trouble with now.  I'm creating a gradient just to start (different on the x and y axes), but for some reason it's only drawing in a fraction of the area it should be.  I think it's something to do with my buffers...

Comment: I suggest starting a new question in which you link this question so people can refer to it, put your new code, and include a picture of the new problem you are having. This will keep the current question clean and usable as a reference to others who are having a problems like the one you originally faced.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of doing that, but I figured it out on my own (it was a bug in my code).  Thanks for all your help, I'll clean up my original post so it's just relevant to my original question.